# Unable to build using ant in eclipse luna and jdk1.5

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am unable to build in Eclipse using Ant. I am using Eclipse Luna, building the project using jdk1.5. It is built properly when I am running the ant build from command prompt, but when I am running the build from eclipse, it is giving the error "Cannot find the main class. Program will exit". Please help.

Comment: Can you post complete error stack/screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved using Kepler instead of Eclipse Luna.